# invocing two jquery statements in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

the function user_delete should
loop over options of a select box and get the class name if the value matches the provides argument
store them in variable

then loop over the document
and delete all elements with that particular class
exception if a span has that class element
only delete the value of that element

the query statements work separately

inserting them into on function seems not to have an effect

```
function user_delete(filename) {
  
     $("#select_updateFile option").each(function(i){
        if ($(this).val() === filename ) {
              var class_name = $(this).attr('class');

        }

        document.querySelectorAll(class_name).forEach(function (e) {
    if ($(e).prev().is("span")) {
        $(e).empty();
    } else {
        e.remove();
     }
}
);


    });

}
```

Comment: Any reason you have the 2 foreach nested one into the other? Seems you could do the first one, add the result to an array, then separately do what ever you do with the queryselector

Comment: logic behind was to loop over that specif select box to get the classname

Comment: Yes but then you do the nested forloop EVERY time, for every element in the list, even the ones that don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the value of the option without looping through by using a selector.

Then if that value exists, find the class. Then for spans, set the innerHTML to empty.

Then you can find the non spans with the same class and remove them from the dom altogether.

The CSS is just there to make it obvious the span is empty but still exists.

```js
function user_delete(filename) {
   opt = document.querySelector("#select_updateFile option[value='" + filename + "']")
   if(opt){
       _class = opt.getAttribute("class")
       spans = document.querySelectorAll("span." + _class)
       spans.forEach(function(span){
         span.innerHTML = "";
       })
       
       nonspans = document.querySelectorAll("." + _class + ":not(span)")
       nonspans.forEach(function(el){
         el.remove();
       })
   
   }
  }

user_delete("aa")
```

```css
span.test{display:block;background:red;height:40px;width:140px;}
```

```html
<span class="test">EMPTY ME</span>

<div class="test">DELETE ME</div>

<select id="select_updateFile">
<option class="test" value="aa">33</option>
<option class="testa" value="bb">22</option>

</select>
```